# Adding a worksheet from an external workbook using VBA

Tags: excel, addition, worksheet, vba

How do I use the `Worksheet.Add` function to add a worksheet from an external workbook?

When I try to add a worksheet from an external workbook I get an error:

> Method 'Add' of object 'Sheets' failed on the third line`

Here is my code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheet1, Count:=2,Type:="\\SharedDrive\Worksheet\Student.xltm")
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Have you looked to see if it works with a local file, rather than the share you've used in your example?

Comment: This is almost identical to your last question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Type:=" has to be a template if you are inserting from another file.

The syntax is

```
expression.Add(Before, After, Count, Type)
```

Where

Type is Optional Variant. Specifies the sheet type. Can be one of the following XlSheetType constants: xlWorksheet, xlChart, xlExcel4MacroSheet, or xlExcel4IntlMacroSheet. If you are inserting a sheet based on an existing template, specify the path to the template. The default value is xlWorksheet.

For example

```
Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheet1, Count:=2, _
Type:="\\SharedDrive\Worksheet\Student.xlt")
```

or

```
Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheet1, Count:=2,_
Type:="\\SharedDrive\Worksheet\Student.xltm")
```

or

```
Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheet1, Count:=2,_
Type:="\\SharedDrive\Worksheet\Student.xltx")
```

xlt - Excel 2003 Template

xltx - Excel 2007/2010 Template

xltm - Excel 2007/2010 Macro-Enabled Template

Comment: I updated the Type but still get the same error. Do I need to mention sheet name somewhere (sheet that I want to insert from the template)? I am trying to insert this sheet in a macro enabled workbook (I tried saving the template as .xltm but still get the same error). Am I missing something here? I have updated my code above.

Comment: Let's take it 1 step at a time :)

1) Create a new template and save it in your local drive. Test it with that File. Does it work?

2) If it does then copy the same template to the shared drive and test it again. Does it work?

We will take it from there :)